# Delete php files in directory with ssh

Tags: ssh

I need a ssh comand to delete logs files via ssh in one folder. I have in my server more than million logs into a folder, but inside there are several folders and I just want to delete logs files with name like this example:

```
aw-anime.php.2481
aw-anime.php.2485
aw-anime.php.2446
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if dir = the folder

```
cd dir
find ./ -name 'aw-anime.php.*' | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh [options] user@hostname rm [options] /path/to/folder/with/logs/aw-anime.php.*
```

This should do what you want, given appropriate options and path.

Comment: So are you looking for a command to run once you are already ssh'd into the machine with the logs, then?